# Cauchy’s Inequality application

Tags: complex-analysis

Supose $f(z)$ is analytic complex function inside $C: |z| ≤ 1$ and continuos in $C$, also

$|f| \leq 2$ for $z \in \{z : |z| = 1, Im z ≥ 0\}$

$|f| \leq 3$ for $z \in \{z : |z| = 1, Im z ≤ 0\}$

Show that $|f'(0)|\leq \sqrt{6}$

Hint: consider $f(z)\cdot f(-z)$

Use Cauchy’s Inequality:

> Let $f(z)$ be analytic inside and on a circle $C$ of radius $r$ and
>   center at $z=a$
>
> $|f^{(n)}(a)|\leq\frac{M\cdot n!}{r^n}$
>
> $n=0,1,2,3,...$
>
> Where $M$ is a constant such that $|f(z)|<M$

Comment: What are your own thoughts?

Comment: I think if I use the hint, $f(z)\cdot f(-z) \leq 6$, but I'm not sure if after that I can do $f(z)^2 \leq 6\rightarrow |f(z)| \leq \sqrt{6}$ and because $n=1$, $a=0$ (radious if circle $C$) and by Cauchy’s Inequality, the statemet is true $|f'(0)| \leq \sqrt{6}$

Comment: is it possible to go from $f(z)\cdot f(−z)\leq 6$ to $f(z)^2 \leq 6\rightarrow|f(z)|\leq\sqrt{6}$ ?, @Henrik